# Unir arrays diferentes em forma de árvore?

Tags: php, array

tenho uma situação em que não estou conseguindo arranjar uma solução.

Suponha que tenhamos dois arrays da seguinte maneira:

```
array('br', 'com', 'example1' )
```

e outro array assim:

```
array('br','com','example2')
```

o que eu gostaria é de transformar estes dois arrays em apenas um de forma que pareça uma árvore de dados assim

```
br
!_com
    !_example1
    |_example2
```

ou se também é possível organizá-los de um formato que possa ler em jSon

```
br:{
   com:{ "example1", "example2" }
}
```

Alguém poderia propor um algorítmo ou existe alguma função em PHP que faça isto?

Comment: Pode dar mais exemplos ? Esse exemplo parece me talvez um pouco forçado ? Cada entrada do array é um nivel da arvore ? Podem ter entradas diferentes ? A ordem pode ser diferente ? A divisão fica sempre no fim ou pode ficar no meio ?

Comment: a ideia é que os valores repetidos na mesma posição dos arrays se tornem nós da arvore. no exemplo os dois arrays tem valores repetidos na primeira posição, então isto se tornaria um nó do array.

Answer (score 0):

finalmente consegui elaborar uma solução para este algoritmo.
Suponha tenhamos o seguinte array:

```
$itens = array( array('br','com','exemplo1'), array('br,'com','exemplo2'));
$result = array(array());
```

No meu caso eu criei uma função que recebe o array final por referência da seguinte maneira:

```
function treeNodesArray( &$result, $itens)
{
    foreach( $itens as $array ){

       $node = &$result;


       foreach( $array as $value )
       {
        if( $node != null && array_key_exists( $value, $node ))
        {
            $node = &$node[$value];

        }else{
            $node[$value] = array();
            $node = &$node[$value];

        }
      }
    }
}

print_r( $result );
```

Obrigado!